# ssh2 library for nodejs: Error: Unable to request a pseudo-terminal

Tags: node.js, ssh

I'm using the ssh2 library for nodejs.

```
# server.coffee
new ssh2.Server
    privateKey: fs.readFileSync './id_rsa'
    port: 57037
, (client) ->
    console.log 'Client connected'

    client.on 'authentication', (ctx) ->
        ctx.accept()
    .on 'ready', ->
        console.log 'Client authenticated'
        client.on 'session', (accept, reject) ->
            console.log 'session'
            session = accept()
            console.log 'accept'
            console.log session.on
            session.on 'shell', (accept, reject, info) ->
                console.log('Client wants to execute: ' + inspect(info.command));
                stream = accept()
                stream.stderr.write 'Error!'
                stream.write 'Just kidding'
                stream.exit 0
                stream.end()
            session.on 'error', ->
                console.log 'error'
```

---

```
# client.coffee
conn = new Client()
conn.on 'ready', ->
    console.log 'Client :: ready'
    conn.shell (err, stream) ->
        console.log 'shell'
        if err then throw err
        stream.on 'close', ->
            console.log 'Stream :: close'
            conn.end()
        .on 'data', (chunk) ->
            console.log 'STDOUT:', data
        .stderr.on 'data', (chunk) ->
            console.log 'STDERR:', data
        stream.end 'ls -al'
.connect()
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to request a pseudo-terminal
    at C:\Users\pv\Proj\test\ssh-test\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:1160:25
    at SSH2Stream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pv\Proj\test\ssh-test\node_modules\ssh2\lib\Channel.js:179:24)
    at SSH2Stream.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at parsePacket (C:\Users\pv\Proj\test\ssh-test\node_modules\ssh2\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\ssh.js:3225:10)
    at SSH2Stream._transform (C:\Users\pv\Proj\test\ssh-test\node_modules\ssh2\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\ssh.js:552:13)
    at SSH2Stream.Transform._read [as __read] (_stream_transform.js:179:10)
    at SSH2Stream._read (C:\Users\pv\Proj\test\ssh-test\node_modules\ssh2\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\ssh.js:213:15)
    at SSH2Stream.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:167:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:288:5)
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not handling the `pty` session event. The default action when there is no event handler is to reject the request. So to allow all `pty` requests, add something like this:

```
session.on 'pty', (accept, reject, info) ->
    accept()
```

Comment: Oh hey, youre the author of `ssh2`! I thought the `shell` event was an alias for this? Thats what the example on the github led me to believe... I'm following the first server example.

Comment: `shell` is a separate thing since you can technically request an interactive shell session without allocating a pty (e.g. the OpenSSH client can do this with the `-T` flag).

Comment: How come my example isnt working then? is shell dependent on `pty`?

Comment: The example isn't working because the client is requesting a pty and the default action if you do not handle a request is to reject it. `shell` is technically separate from `pty` as I previously mentioned.